# Is it possible to use AWS API Gateway as a ZIP file download proxy?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I currently have an online service which returns a zip file (at URL A), need to move that service to a subpath of another URL (B/subpath). Since I cannot change the DNS to make A point to B/subpath (and have a list of clients pointing to A), I'm trying to set up a a **proxy using AWS API Gateway**, but I'm **not being able to receive the file**.

I can successfully proxy calls which simply return a plain text response, but the call to get the file does not download a correct zip file (though it sends a 200 response).

The file I'm getting when calling the proxy is 15Kb (and can't be unzipped), while the file I get when calling the original endpoint is 8.1Kb (and can be unzipped).

Is it possible to **proxy a file through API Gateway**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary content is not currently supported in API Gateway. I'm assuming the file server is responding with content 'application/octet-stream' which is binary data. If the file server can response with base64 encoded data instead (UTF-8 encoded) then API Gateway will be able to proxy that, but then the client needs to decode from base64 so that might not be viable for you.